# jQuery fancybox link inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div containing information. Wraped around the div I have a 'a' tag so that when a user clicks anywhere around the div the fancy box opens.

However inside the div I andother link that when clicked instead of opening the fancy box it deleted the whole div. I used return false in the click event for the delete which worked.

I have now had to add .live to the click because newly created elemnet were not getting the click event.

Since then though when I click the delete link the div does delete but the fancy box opens also.

Thanks for any help.

```
        $(".listContent").live('mouseenter', function(){
         $(this).fancybox({
            'type':'ajax',
            });
        });

        $("div.removeCompare").live("click", function() {
            $(this).parents(".listingContainer").remove();                                          
            return false;
        });
```

Div

```
           <div class="listingContainer grid_9 alpha omega">                    
                <a class="listContent" href="adContent.html">
                    <div class="listingWrapper">
                        <div class="grid_8 alpha omega">
                        <div class="listingContent">
                            <div class="imgHolder">
                                <img src="imgs/cars/SearchThumb-10053325.jpg" width="100" height="75">
                            </div>
                            <div class="descHolder">
                                <div id="cars"></div>                            
                                <h3>Fancy Car</h3><div class="removeCompare">Remove</div>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri ex duis maiorum commune, illud viderer suscipiantur eam an. Dolorum recteque qui in. Pro inani nulla tacimates ex, qu</p>
                                <span class="listingPrice">€4,000</span>
                                <span class="listingDate">Listed: Today</span>
                                <span class="listingLocation">Co. Waterford</span>
                                <span class="listingViews">Viewed: 20 Times</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goTo goTo_unfocus grid_1 alpha omega">
                        <div class="gotoWrapper">
                                Click to View
                                <div class="imgVeiw"></div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--End listingWrapper-->
                </a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**
[This code](http://jsfiddle.net/zn4xq/) should most probably work.

```
$(".listContent").live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).fancybox({
        'type': 'ajax'
    });
    console.log('inside fancybox creator');
});

$("div.removeCompare").live('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('inside remove');
    $(this).parents(".listingContainer").remove();
});
```

I think your problem was with `event propagation` - when you click on a child element the related event of parent too fires up. So `e.stopPropagation()` will stop that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried the above, but still getting redirected, both event fire in the console as expected

Comment: @KeithPower Are you still having `$(".listContent").live('mouseenter'...`. I cant think of why you use that event. Any way my demo code works fine. What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: you are 100% right, I missed that. Thanks for the help, really appreciated :-)

Comment: Hi sransara, still an issue, now that I change the fancy box to click it does not work. If I click it takes me to the page instead of loading into the fancy box, but when I use the back button it works but the remove issue appears agin where it will remove but also load the fancy box. Is there a way to get it work with mouseenter as fancy box suggest, thanks.

Comment: @KeithPower How about adding `e.preventDefault();` as the first line of `$(".listContent").live('click', function(e){...}`

Comment: @KeithPower I've updated the code and the demo link. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the click event function of the div, unbind the mouseenter event for the inner element (which opens the fancybox), using the .die('mouseenter') event handler unbinding syntax.

Comment: thanks for that. Not quiting working this is the code I have    $(".listContent").live('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).fancybox({
    'type':'ajax',
    });
   $('div.removeCompare').die("mouseenter");
   });

Comment: You need to do this: `code`$('div.removeCompare').live("click", function() { $(this).parents(".listingContainer").remove(); $(this).children(‘.listContent’).die('mouseenter'); return false; });`code`

Comment: sorry still learning javascript and jQuery, understanding the .die is a big help. The code still will not work but I suspect that it is because the .childern. I have posted the actual div the .removeCompare is in?